# Write to db efficiently from a multithread application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, multithreading

I have a server application that receives data from clients that must be stored in a database.

Client/server communication is made with ServiceStack, and for every client call there can be 1 or more records to be written.

The clients doesn't need to wait the data to be written or to know if the data has been written.

At my customer site the database sometimes may be unavailable for short times so I want to retry the writing until the database is available again.

I can't use a servicebus, or other software..it must be only my server and the database.

I considered two possibilities:

1) fire a thread for every call to write a record (or group of records with a multiple insert) that in case of failure retries until it has success

2) enqueque the data to be written in a global in-memory list, and have a single background thread to continuosly make a single call to the db (with a multiple insert)
What do you consider the most efficient way do do it? or do you have another proposal?

Option 1 is easier, but I'm worried to have too many threads running at the same time, expecially if the db gets unavailable.

In case I'll follow the second route, my idea is:

1) every server thread opened by a client locks the global list to insert 1 or more records to write to the db, release the lock and closes

2) the background thread locks the global list that has for example 50 records, makes a deep copy to a temp list, unlocks the global list

3) the server thread continues to add data to the global list, in the meantime the background thread tries to write the 50 records, retrying until it has success

4) when the background thread manages to write, it locks again the global list (that maybe now has 80 records), remove the first 50 that has been written, and everything starts again

Is there a better way to do this?

--------- EDIT ----------
My issue is that I don't want in any way the client to have to wait, not even for the adding of the record-to-be-sent to a blocked list (that happens when the writing thread writes or tries to write the list to the DB).
That's why in my solution I lock the list only for the time to copy the list to a temporary list that will be written to db.
I'm just wondering if this is crazy and there is a much simpler solution that I'm not following.

Comment: `At my customer site the database sometimes may be unavailable for short times` - have you thought about fixing that issue?

Comment: Have you considered message queuing (e.g. MSMQ or RabbitMQ)?

Comment: I would try a BlockingCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx

Comment: AAron: It's not my SQLServer to manage, I warned the customer but it seems they can't do anything about it...once it was a backup, once a heavy processing job of another tool etc.. I simply can't fix that part but still want to be able not to lose my data.

Comment: lukiffer: as I stated, I can't add other software, only my software

Comment: I'll investigate the BlockingConnection, but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the problem is as follows:
1. Client sends a data to be inserted to DB
2. Server receives the data and inserts to DB
3. Client doesn't want to know if data is inserted properly or not


In this case, I would suggest, Let server create a single Queue which holds the data to be inserted to DB, let receive thread just receive the data from client and insert into inmemory Queue, this queue can be emptied by another thread which takes care of writing to DB to persist.

You may even use file based queue or priority queue or just in-memory queue for storing the records temporarily.

Comment: yes, this is more or less the second route I proposed, I was wondering if there was a different way

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .Net Thread Pool you don't need to worry about creating too many threads as thread lifetime is managed for you.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(DbWriteMethodHere)
```

If you want to be smarter you could add the records you want to commit to a `BlockingCollection` - and then have a thread do `BlockingCollection<T>.Take(50)` which will block until there is a big enough batch to commit.

Comment: but then, while the thread sends the data to the db, the main thread is unable to add data to the collection, so my application is blocked, right?

Comment: and anyway, if the DB is blocked, wouldn't firing 1000 for example threads create problems?